# What does the Get-Command parameter -commandCapability do?

Tags: powershell-3.0

I was researching Get-Command in PowerShell 3 when I saw –CommandCapability listed at the end of the Parameters.

My question is how do you get this –CommandCapability parameter to work?

Answer (score 1):

Get-Command | select Capability should give you some clues.
Also Get-Command | Group Capability to see what are possible options.

Basically, it's there to tell a difference between "normal" cmdlets, scripts, CIM cmdlets and workflows. I would say it's extension to currently existing classification of CommandType(s).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  However, I cannot get any results with

Comment: It may be related to build I think? On Win8 server beta I get it, on RC I do not get anything... :| But than again: I do not have this parameter on newer build too...

Answer (score 0):

@Guy - I don't see a -CommandCapability in the latest shipping PowerShell V3:

```
Parameter Set: CmdletSet
Get-Command [[-ArgumentList] <Object[]> ] [-All] [-ListImported] [-Module <String[]> ] [-Noun <String[]> ] [-ParameterName <String[]> ] [-ParameterType <PSTypeName[]> ] [-Syntax] [-TotalCount <Int32> ] [-Verb <String[]> ] [ <CommonParameters>]

Parameter Set: AllCommandSet
Get-Command [[-Name] <String[]> ] [[-ArgumentList] <Object[]> ] [-All] [-CommandType <CommandTypes> ] [-ListImported] [-Module <String[]> ] [-ParameterName <String[]> ] [-ParameterType <PSTypeName[]> ] [-Syntax] [-TotalCount <Int32> ] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

Did you mean CommandType?

Comment: Get-Command [[-Name] <String[]>] [[-ArgumentList] <Object[]>] [-All [<SwitchParameter>]] [-CommandCapability

BuildVersion   6.2.8370.0 
PSVersion      3.0     
CLRVersion     4.0.30319.269